# Help understanding remark on Greenberg and Harper text on cohomology chapter

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am working through Greenberg and Harper text  and I don't understand a remark. I think it should be very easy to gasp but I don't see what it means:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

My problem is with the remark 23.0. Could you explain it to me. I am not sure if by $S(X)$ he means the complex with the modules of singular chains or the one with modules of singular cochains. I suppose that it is the first one. Could you confirm it?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a "typo": it should be a tensor product instead of a direct sum. And I guess he means by $S(X)$ singular chains, since they are free and the last isomorphism looks like the cochain module which is defined via chains.

Comment: @user60589 that make sense! Thanks.